# How to block a seller on Craigslist?

Tags: spam-prevention, ads, craigslist

This single user currently has **543 postings**, all basically the same 2 ads.

They use keyword spam in the ad body to appear in substantially *every* Craigslist search I perform.

How can I **block or mute a Craigslist user** so that I *never* see another one of their ads?

If it can't be done via a CL account setting, how can I do so via an ad-blocker program?

---

I'm aware of other potential solutions to improve my search:

- Filter "by Owner" so that I do not see any dealer results.
- Add `-cargo` or other similar negative search terms.
- Flag the ads by this user.

But this question is about blocking a seller entirely.

---

[image: CL spam]